# How can I cleanly pass a parameter to a delegate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, delegates

Below is MSDN code from delegate section.

The code is working as excepted but I would like to know how do I input message into this small logging component.

Which one is the correct way to input an error message ?
Should I use : `Logger.WriteMessage or Logger.LogMessage`
Although both is printing a message to the screen

```
Logger.WriteMessage(error_msg1);
```

or

```
Logger.LogMessage(error_msg2);
```

```
using System;

namespace DelegateTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string error_msg1 = "101 : Error Disk";
            string error_msg2 = "104 : Error Retriving";

            Logger.WriteMessage += LoggingMethods.LogToConsole;


            Logger.WriteMessage(error_msg1);
            Logger.LogMessage(error_msg2);


            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class Logger
    {
        public static Action<string> WriteMessage;

        public static void LogMessage(string msg)
        {
            WriteMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    public static class LoggingMethods
    {
        public static void LogToConsole(string message)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A delegate is essentially a function, not a component. You don't put anything into it, you call it and pass the data you want as parameters, the same as a method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos First off, thanks for assisting me. I know that delegate is a method/function, I used the term component to refer to the whole app as a logging component.  By the way, MSDN doc also calls it a logging component.  The thing is sometimes people use delegates in many ways which makes it difficult to understand. I see other exampled which I need to analyze. **Can you please give me a practical example of a delegate ?**

Comment: When you use LINQ, all lambdas are `Func<>` delegates. A delegate is more-or-less a function pointer, allowing you to pass functions around as if they were data. When you use `Where` you tell LINQ to filter some items using the delegate you passed as an argument to `Where`.

Comment: Your code doesn't include anything named `LoggerCore`.  It's hard to answer the specific question you are asking.  It's also worth noting that although the code you show does use delegate features, the idiom you are using (directly using `+=` to initialize a delegate instance) is not something you see in everyday code.  Delegates are used everywhere in .NET code.  They are _very rarely_ used in the way you are using them

Comment: So from the above MSDN code, which one is the correct use to input data ? Logger.WriteMessage("error message text") or Logger.LogMessage("error message text")

Comment: @Flydog57 I edited the first post. By the way, it's not my code, it's MSDN documentation code. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/delegates-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LogMessage. It is part of the Logger's intended API and may add extra functionality (adding a time-stamp). It should also guard against WriteMessage being null.

`Logger.WriteMessage`  is the 'plug-in' point.  You shouldn't use it to write anything and you shouldn't assume it *is not null*